# Radial Gradient with Compass specify size in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to do a background glow effect using compass and a radial gradient, it works fine in chrome as I put in the size of the gradient but in firefox nothing is rendered.

I've made a codepen for the example which works in chrome

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmkEu

The sass I'm using is

```
@include background-image(
    radial-gradient(top center, 700px 300px, lighten(red, 20) 40%, red 80%)
    );
```

Is there a way to get this to work in Firefox?  It works if I replace the 700px 300px with say circle but then its not the shape I want.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with radial gradients, but the problem appears to be the `top center` argument.  If I remove it, the elliptical gradient appears in the center of the page.  Opera behaves the same way as Firefox.

Comment: @cimmanon, it is the location of the top center argument, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this [article](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), here is a link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ArEuI)

```
    @include background(radial-gradient(circle 700px 300px at top center , lighten(red, 20) 40%, red 80%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent);
```